# sql - compare two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`. They both have same columns, `program_id`, `scheduled_time` and `timezone_id`.

I want to retrieve the rows whose have same `program_id` and `timezone_id`, but have different `scheduled_time` from `table1`.

So here is the sql that I tried:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.program_id = t2.program_id 
  and t1.timezone_id = t2.timezone_id 
  and t1.scheduled_time != t2.scheduled_time;
```

But I still see rows that have same `program_id`, `scheduled_time` and `timezone_id`.

Could someone fix the sql?

Thanks.

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Is that *really* the SQL you tried? Because it never seems to define `t1` . . .

Comment: See (and **embrace**!) [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - use **proper** ANSI/ISO JOIN syntax

Comment: This query (adding a `t1`, of course) actually seems to work for me in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.* 
FROM
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.program_id = t2.program_id AND t1.timezone_id = t2.timezone_id 
WHERE
     t1.scheduled_time <> t2.scheduled_time
```

Basically, do an `INNER JOIN` on the common columns (`program_id` and `timezone_id`) and make sure the `scheduled_time` column has a different value.

Also: in SQL use the `<>` operator - `!=` is for C# / VB.NET ....

Comment: I still see rows that have same program_id, scheduled_time and timezone_id with the query. At this point, i am kind of confused.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use subquery:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where exists
(
  select 1
  from table2 t2
  where t1.program_id = t2.program_id 
  and t1.timezone_id = t2.timezone_id 
  and t1.scheduled_time != t2.scheduled_time;
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I would recommend always specifying a column list instead of using `SELECT *`.

```
SELECT t1.program_id, t1.scheduled_time, t1.timezone_id
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON 
    t2.program_id = t1.program_id AND
    t2.timezone_id = t1.timezone_id
WHERE
    t2.scheduled_time <> t1.scheduled_time
```